# Auto refresh android fragment until condition is met

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, runnable

I'm building a multi-fragment app for android. I'm now executing in my third fragment, and I'm trying to get it to auto refresh until a timer reaches 0, after which it should open the next fragment and transition. Someone suggested I use the following to auto-refresh, but upon the condition being met, the app closes and Android tells me it stopped working. The 4th fragment isn't shown at all.

This is the way I am refreshing in my code, in the onCreateView() for my 3rd fragment:

```java
refresh = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isRunning) {
            // do some stuff here
            handler.postDelayed(refresh, 500);
        } else
            return;
    }
};
handler.post(refresh);
```

I am making calls to the UI in the refresh run() since I am updating multiple textviews. Should I make a seperate thread for this?

Answer (score 0):

To refresh fragment in android use the following code.
**Fragment refreshing method**

```
public void refreshFragment(){
    Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment); 
    fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

You can place it in a handler and invoke the method whenever needed.
Note: Make sure to call method inside

> runOnUiThread(new Runnable{//code here})